# Can de4dot deobfuscate Dotfuscator Professional?

Tags: obfuscation, deobfuscation, .net

I ran de4dot on a Xamarin app obfuscated using Dotfuscator Professional. However, there's still the random switches and strange ints everywhere. Can de4dot decode this? If not, is there another tool that can?
I've opened it with dotPeek and dnSpy as well to the same result.

[Here's an example.](https://hastebin.com/uwulipuyit.cs) Most of the logic I need is in chains of these tasks. O6.K does not even exist.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of those random switches and ints? Sometimes these ints value are in hexadecimal.

Comment: @Biswapriyo https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/430912697320734751/484481149687824425/unknown.png

Comment: Here's the corresponding Dotfuscator page on the feature -> https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/protection_obfuscation_control_flow.html

Comment: That probably wasn't the greatest example. There's sections of the code that make no sense and reference variables in the class that don't exist. I'll find a better example when I get home, sorry.

Comment: https://hastebin.com/uwulipuyit.cs

Comment: It uses a Coral namespace which I'm not familiar with. But you go with a naive approach. Copy the whole code in a visual studio project and run it in a debugger and see those values and code flow.

Comment: If that's the only way, I don't think there's a solution to this..
It's a decompiled Xamarin app. There's no executable to run, so can't debug it. Copy-pasting the code into .cs files wouldn't work either, because the DLLs themselves have been broken. Thanks for all the help anyways!